# How to futureproof thread-safe concurrent access to std::shared_ptr std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, c++20, unique-ptr

What are some recommended strategies for future-proofing present-day C++ coding of concurrent access to `std::shared_ptr`(-like) and `std::unique_ptr`(-like) data structures, as the C++ language spec evolves in this area?

Background:

Circa 2021, available C++ language constructs for managing access to `std::shared_ptr`(-like) and `std::unique_ptr`(-like) smart pointers in concurrency-friendly ways are in flux.  For example C++20 support for `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` hasn't made it very far into compiler in the wild yet, but the C++20 spec tells us it is coming.

I'm engaged in non-trivial multi-threaded development and need to be able to pass smart pointers (both shared and unique) between threads via (hopefully lock-free) queues and use them in various thread-safe ways.  I'd like to develop this code in a way that allows it to be easily upgraded to modern language features once they become available.  The ideal would be to be able to do this upgrade easily from a central place, such as would be the case if changing the definition of a CPP-macro and coding in terms of those macros.

Does anyone know of a good strategy (A good set of CPP macros perhaps?) for future-proofing present-day concurrency code?

[ CLARIFYING EDIT after some good comments (Thanks everyone) ]
From what I gather:

1. Different instances of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` may be read/written, from different threads without an issue, (like when different instances are passed-in to different threads) but the object instance (or memory) they point to may NOT be safely accessed by multiple threads at the same time (so you should use a mutex, or another method to access the pointed-to-object if this is the use case). *[ Thanks Alex Guteniev for that clarity ]*
2. The SAME instance of a std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr may be read/written by threads in a safe way using (pre-C++20: `std::atomic_load/store` etc, AND post-C++20: `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` or `std::atomic<std::unique_ptr>` )  **My thought is that this might be a place to use CPP MACROS, such as SHARED_GET, SHARED_SET, UNIQUE_GET, UNIQUE_SET that'd centralize the changes you'd need to make to go from C++17 to C++20.** *[ Thanks NicolBolas for the clarity on what is actually coming in C++20. As was pointed out: the link I provided in the comments below is outdated, so be careful not to consider it fact.]*

3. If you are passing `std::unique_ptr` between threads using `std::move` to pass the pointed-to-memory along, and using queues to enforce that only a single thread has access at any given time, you can use both the std_unique pointers themselves AND the pointed-to-memory in the thread that receives the pointer without any mutexes, or other protection against resource contention.

Because of my confusion when asking, my original question was perhaps confusing.  Now I'd rephrase the question as: I'm looking for a set of access CPP macros #defines, that detect C++17 and C++20 and use that version's cleanest/correct definition for the following operations:

- MAKE_LOCAL_SHARED: Create/load a local std::shared_ptr instance from
  a common/shared instance that the thread can read/write without
  contention with the original.  It should point to the same memory
  that the common/shared one pointed to
- BEGIN_USE_SHARED_TGT: Create an
  hold a `std::lock_guard/mutex` within the scope of which the
  pointed-to-memory of a local `std::shared_ptr` instance can be safely
  used.
- END_USE_SHARED_TGT: (probably just a closing brace?) Release
  the `std::lock_guard/mutex` when done using the pointed-to-memory
- BEGIN_USE_UNIQUE_TGT, END_USE_UNIQUE_TGT (same as above for
  `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: You could use a templated type alias that either refers to `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` if it is supported, or to an alternative blocking or platform-specific solution when it isn't. Just make sure your alternative is interface-compatible with `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: I'd guess that the future C++ will maintain backwards compatibility with the current requirements for those objects for thread safety, unless the threading model changes in such as way that it would not be possible to be backwards compatible.

Comment: Are you _implementing_ lock-free containers, or are you asking about usage of threadsafe containers that _hold_ smart pointers?  The former is very tricky and the later is very simple.

Comment: Does your problem require a C++ solution?  There are some languages that handle multithreading — *in my opinion* — a little more gracefully than C++ (such as D, Rust, Ada, Haskell, OCaml, F#).

Comment: @Eljay yes, I do need this to be C++ as the work in question is within a larger C++ codebase.

Comment: @Drew Dorman I've adapted a lock-free queue from https://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/writing-lock-free-code-a-corrected-queue/210604448?pgno=2 to use a node pool for the queue nodes. I am mostly asking about the way I -code- the usage of smart pointers in thread-safe ways.

Comment: @Dave: "*C++ language constructs for managing access to std::shared_ptr(-like) and std::unique_ptr(-like) smart pointers in concurrency-friendly ways are in flux*". No they aren't. `atomic<shared_ptr>` is simply a nicer wrapper around something C++11 already allowed. And even so, it's kind of irrelevant, because `atomic<shared_ptr>` is about allowing multiple threads to have atomic access to a specific `shared_ptr` object, not the object it points to. That's different from simply passing a `shared_ptr` to another thread.

Comment: @NicolBolas, _atomic<shared_ptr> is simply a nicer wrapper around something C++11 already allowed_  - not necessarily, since `atomic<shared_ptr>` can be lock free. But otherwise agree

Comment: @NicolBolas I was referring to the fact that C++20 is going to introduce new atomic smart pointers.  (see: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/atomic-smart-pointers).  Admittedly, my head is swimming a bit in some confusion over which of the various available flavors of these are appropriate (std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<Type>> vs std::atomic_shared_ptr<Type> vs. std::atomic_load/store) and what I have to be careful to avoid in their use in different threads without a mutex.

Comment: Also, when I say "Use" (the smart/unique pointer) I'm referring both to accessing the instance the pointer points to, but also reassigning, or reseting the pointer itself (ie the pointer needing to modify its ctrl block).

Comment: @Dave: There is no `atomic_shared_ptr<Type>` type. That post was from 2017, and that was talking about an *early* version of the proposal. The committee took that proposal and renamed the type `atomic<shared_ptr<T>>` to make it clear exactly what it is.

Comment: @NicolBolas That is -very- good to know!  I really appreciate you clarifying that, as I was operating under false assumptions and it was confusing me for sure.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm engaged in non-trivial multi-threaded development and need to be able to pass smart pointers (both shared and unique) between threads via (hopefully lock-free) queues and use them in various thread-safe ways.

When using a (lock-free) queue, you don't access produced and consumed elements at the same time.

For accessing **different** variables `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are already safe. When two `shared_ptr`s point to the same object, there is a guarantee that manipulating these `shared_ptr`s in different threads is thread safe, usually implemented using reference counting. Different `unique_ptr`s don't  point to the same object.

Just use `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` as usual if you just put them to a queue and don't really access the same variable from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!  I initially adopted a strict unique_ptr ONLY approach, using 1x1 queues so it was completely obvious which thread had access to the unique_ptr and what it pointed at.  That was largely because I'm not fully confident I understand all of the different shared/unique/atomic combinations (see comment to NicolBolas above for the different flavors).  What I'd like to do is relax the requirement to copy the unique_ptr when I want to send it along to multiple downstream processing threads.  I'd like to turn it into a shared_ptr (avoid the copy) and send it on.

Comment: My question about future proofing this is to centralize whatever pattern I implement so that it can be updated when C++20 comes around, but only if I'm going to actually need those new types.  Before the future arrives, I still have to sort out the present! :)

Comment: @Dave, you can wrap `template<T> using SharedPtr = std::share_ptr<T>` if you like. But I don't think this is neccessary. `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is not a replacement for `std::shared_ptr<T>`, it is rather a replacement for `std::shared_ptr<T>` protected by mutex.